# How to use a page block table in a visualforce custom components?

Tags: salesforce, batch-processing, apex-code, visualforce

I want to add a custom VF component to display the batch job details in a pageblock table. However my component aint saving, it says:  Error    Error: Read only property 'c:batchDetailsComponent.BatchJobDetails' 
Please help.

This is the visualforce component:

```
    <apex:component controller="BatchOpportunityDetailsExtension">
        <apex:attribute name="batchJob" type="List" assignTo="{!BatchJobDetails}" description="" />
            <apex:form >
                <apex:pageBlock>
                    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!batchJob}" var="batch">
                        <apex:column value="{!batch.CompletedDate}"/>    
                        <apex:column value="{!batch.JobItemsProcessed}"/>    
                        <apex:column value="{!batch.NumberOfErrors}"/> 
                    </apex:pageblockTable>  
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
    </apex:component>
```

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Opportunity_Scheduled_Information__c" 
     extensions="BatchOpportunityDetailsExtension">
       <c:oppScheduleComponent componentValue="{!batchJob}"/>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
    public class BatchOpportunityDetailsExtension {

public List<AsyncApexJob> batchJobDetails = new List<AsyncApexJob>();    
public Opportunity_Scheduled_Information__c pageController {get;set;}
public BatchOpportunityDetailsExtension() {}

public BatchOpportunityDetailsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Total_Amount__c', 'Number_of_Opportunities__c'});
pageController = (Opportunity_Scheduled_Information__c)controller.getRecord();

BatchJobDetails = [ SELECT id,ApexClassID,CompletedDate,JobType,JobItemsProcessed,NumberOfErrors,MethodName,Status,ExtendedStatus,TotalJobItems FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ApexClassId='01p7F000000bKIlQAM' LIMIT 50] ;   

}

public List<AsyncApexJob> getBatchJobDetails()
{
    return BatchJobDetails ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the access for your component to `global`.
Like this: `<apex:component access="global" controller="BatchOpportunityDetailsExtension">`